# How to ignore mongodb duplicate key error with insertMany?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have tried the following code I found on internet but it didn't work.

`client.withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED)`

I also set ordered to false and it didn't work.

Is there any options to chang the behavior when inserting a duplicate key record? Or should I change anything on the server side?

Comment: How about not inserting duplicate keys?

Comment: @lexicore No, the dataset has some data with the same id (I use the id for "_id"). If mongodb can't do this I have to manually remove the duplicate data. But I don't want to do this.

Comment: Instead of insert shouldn't you use upsert?

Comment: @Bhardwaj I change to upsert, thanks for your hint.